# Electron : How to consume readable stream in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would like to ask if there is any way of consuming a readable stream in an electron without using `HTTP`.
I have tried creating the server and streaming over it but going that way will disable the `node intregration` for that streaming page so I just wonder is there any other way to consume readable stream?